# Dynamically created select menu on change not working

Tags: jquery, select

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/FTHVJ/

And demo here - http://ttmt.org.uk/select

I know this looks a little crazy but it's cloest I could get to the actual code.

I have an on 'change' event handler on a select menu #menu_One

This then adds a new select menu #menu_Two that is saved in jquery as a variable.

I'm then trying to add an on 'change' event handler to this added select menu.

The on 'change' event doesn't work on thw added select menu.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

      <!--jQuery-->
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


      <!--css-->

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        body{
          background:#eee;
        }
        #wrap{
          max-width:800px;
          margin:0 auto;
          background:#fff;
          height:1000px;
          padding:50px;
        }
        #new_select{
          height:50px;
          margin:20px 0 0 0;
          padding:10px 0 0 0;
          background:red;
        }
      </style>

      <title>Title of the document</title>
      </head>

    <body>

      <div id="wrap">

        <select id="menu_One">
          <option>Menu One 1</option>
          <option>Menu One 2</option>
          <option>Menu One 3</option>
          <option>Menu One 4</option>
          <option>Menu One 5</option>  
        </select>  

        <div id="new_select">
        </div>  
      </div>

    </body>


      <script>

        $(function(){

          var select_two = "<select id='menu_Two'>";
              select_two += "<option>Menu Two 1</option>";
              select_two += "<option>Menu Two 2</option>";
              select_two += "<option>Menu Two 3</option>";
              select_two += "<option>Menu Two 4</option>";
              select_two += "</select>";


          $('#menu_One').on('change', function(){
            $('#new_select').append(select_two);
          });


          $('#menu_Two').on('change', function(){
            alert('here');
          })

        });

      </script>



    </html>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For dynamically created elements, you need to use the [`.on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#new_select').on('change', '#menu_Two', function(){
    alert('here');
});
```

Event listeners can only be attached to elements that are in the DOM, not elements that don't exist at the time.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the `$(document).on` code because the more specific selector should be more efficient.

Comment: Can you please look into my code and identify why change event is not working on newly added element [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay141194/rf4Lxu54/)

Answer (score 25):

Try:

```
$(document).on('change', '#menu_Two', function(){
        alert('here');
      });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FTHVJ/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes,this is working

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't add the event handler until you've added the DOM node:

```
$(function(){

  var select_two = "<select id='menu_Two'>";
      select_two += "<option>Menu Two 1</option>";
      select_two += "<option>Menu Two 2</option>";
      select_two += "<option>Menu Two 3</option>";
      select_two += "<option>Menu Two 4</option>";
      select_two += "</select>";


  $('#menu_One').on('change', function(){
    $('#new_select').append(select_two);
    $('#menu_Two').on('change', function(){
      alert('here');
    })
  });
});
```

With fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cjcLU/

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it

```
$(document).on('change', "body", function(){
            $( ".ui-selectmenu" ).selectmenu();
        });
```