# Change event on dynamic select does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select, jquery-events

I have simple HTML:

```
<select name="task-categories-select" id="task-categories-select" class="form-control">
    <option selected=""> </option>
</select>
```

Then I dynamically add options (with help of `Backbone.js`). As result, I have the following `HTML`:

```
<select name="task-categories-select" id="task-categories-select" class="form-control">
    <option selected=""> </option>
    <option value="47">Task type 47</option>
    <option value="76">Task type 76</option>
    <option value="25">Task type 25</option>
    <option value="44">Task type 44</option>
</select>
```

I want to listen event on change option. I have the following jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', "#task-categories-select", function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

It correctly works in Chrome. **But**, when I change option first time, it does not work in Firefox. Then, when I change option second time, it works correctly.

P.S. Also, I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746467/1756750).

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl, Unfortunately, my problem is not reproduced. http://jsfiddle.net/Hixon10/41st04pp/2/

Comment: my guess is your problem lies elsewhere. Are any errors thrown?

Comment: @charlietfl, there is no any errors in console. I successfully get data from server, then I render this data in set of options. I solve my problem with very, very dirty workaround. `if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {//..} else {//..}`