# Dynamically creating droppable div with script also dynamically created

Tags: javascript, php, html, drag-and-drop, drag

I am dynamically creating a list of droppable divs with the javascript also dynamically included. The php looks like this:

```
echo "<li class=\"grayborder txdkgray\"><div id=\"queue".$i."\" style=\"width:300px; height:30px; text-align:center;\">*Drag a file here to run* </div></li>";
echo "<script> $('#queue".$i."').droppable( {hoverClass: 'hovered', drop: handleQueueDrop} ); </script>";
```

The problem is that the divs it creates are not working, I can't drop anything into them and the function doesn't run when I do. Is this a problem which the way I am echoing them?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the source code after openning the page with a browser ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically created select menu on change not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746381/dynamically-created-select-menu-on-change-not-working)

Comment: @ElheniMokhles I can't post pictures(I need more reputation) however with the edits from jperelli the script tags are working like normal tags in developer tools(with a drop down and highlighted red words

Answer (score 0):

You need an [space here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887069/does-html5-requires-spaces-between-attributes-that-are-of-quoted-values)

```
... id=\"queue".$i."\"style=\"width:300 ...
```

like this

```
... id=\"queue".$i."\" style=\"width:300 ...
```

Also, you should run your code after load event. Convert this

```
echo "<script> $('#queue".$i."').droppable( {hoverClass: 'hovered', drop: handleQueueDrop} ); </script>";
```

to this

```
echo "<script> $(function(){ $('#queue".$i."').droppable( {hoverClass: 'hovered', drop: handleQueueDrop} ); }) </script>";
```

Comment: The script tags are now looking like normal script tags in developer tools, it hide the text and lets you drop down and highlights #queue0 and hovered in red but it still doesn't run the function

Comment: The script isn't adding the ui-droppable class to the div like it is supposed to

Comment: Did you put the jquery and jquery-ui required scripts? Is there any error in the developer tools?

Comment: The code for the droppable divs work so I assume all the scripts are there and it worked when it wasn't being created dynamically. There are no other errors

Comment: Make sure that in the page appears first the jquery script, then jquery-ui, and then this droppable script of yours

Comment: I finally fixed it by making a function that runs after the elements are added which select all of them and add the class